# iterating through a div to look for all element of each class is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Alright, I just started playing around with javascript so I need to iterate through a div that has many classes with same name but unique ids in order to retrieve the unique id and the innerHTML of the id.
This is the html

```
<div id="uploader">
<div class="row uploadDoc">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="docErr">Please upload valid file</div>
        <!--error-->
        <div class="fileUpload btn btn-orange">
            <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/136/136549.svg" class="icon">
            <span class="upl" id="upload">Upload document</span>
            <input type="file" class="upload up" id="up" onchange="readURL(this);">
        </div>
        <!-- btn-orange -->
    </div>
    <!-- col-3 -->
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="document_name" placeholder="Document Name">
    </div>
    <!--col-8-->
    <div class="col-sm-1"><a class="btn-check"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
    <!-- col-1 -->
</div>
<!--row-->


<div class="row uploadDoc">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="docErr">Please upload valid file</div>
        <!--error-->
        <div class="fileUpload btn btn-orange"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/136/136549.svg" class="icon"><span class="upl" id="upload3">Upload document</span><input type="file" class="upload up" id="up" onchange="readURL(this);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Doc3note" name="" placeholder="Note"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"><a class="btn-check"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
</div>




<div class="row uploadDoc">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="docErr">Please upload valid file</div>
        <!--error-->
        <div class="fileUpload btn btn-orange"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/136/136549.svg" class="icon"><span class="upl" id="upload4">Upload document</span><input type="file" class="upload up" id="up" onchange="readURL(this);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Doc4note" name="" placeholder="Note"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"><a class="btn-check"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
</div>




<div class="row uploadDoc">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="docErr">Please upload valid file</div>
        <!--error-->
        <div class="fileUpload btn btn-orange"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/136/136549.svg" class="icon"><span class="upl" id="upload5">Upload document</span><input type="file" class="upload up" id="up" onchange="readURL(this);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Doc5note" name="" placeholder="Note"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"><a class="btn-check"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
</div>




<div class="row uploadDoc">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="docErr">Please upload valid file</div>
        <!--error-->
        <div class="fileUpload btn btn-orange"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/136/136549.svg" class="icon"><span class="upl" id="upload6">Upload document</span><input type="file" class="upload up" id="up" onchange="readURL(this);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Doc6note" name="" placeholder="Note"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"><a class="btn-check"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
</div>
```

I want to get the id name and innerhtml of the class "form-control" for each class "row uplaod" so I tried this

```
 $('.row uploadDoc').each(function(){ 
  console.log(this)
  var targetdiv = this.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0];
 console.log(targetdiv)
 })
```

and this

```
$("uploadDoc").each(function(i) {

var targetdiv = getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0].innerHTML;
console.log(targetdiv)


});
```

but none of them works, nothing is displayed. How can I get the id and innerHTML of each class "form-control"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an element that has multiple class names, you do not put a space between them in the jQuery selector.  Adding the space will make it look for the second class name as a child of the first.

Try `.row.uploadDoc` in your selector.

```
 $('.row.uploadDoc').each(function(){ 
  console.log(this)
  var targetdiv = this.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0];
 console.log(targetdiv)
 })
```

Your second selector would also work, you were just missing the `.` `$(".uploadDoc")...`.  It just wouldn't require the `uploadDoc` element to also have the `row` class.

---

After you get that going you may run into another problem:

```
this.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0].innerHTML;
```

That line will not use the scope of the element to find `form-control` classes.  You can add that functionality to the jQuery selector though

```
 $('.row.uploadDoc .form-control').each(function(){ 
    console.log($(this)[0]); //each form-control element that is a child of a .row.uploadDoc element
 });
```

This uses a space in the selector (our bug above), this time on purpose to find children.